# Why doesn't lemmatizer doesnt work in some words?

Tags: python, nltk

I updated the wordnet package through spyder to understand if lemmatization happens. I don't see it across multiple attempts. Any help

```
In [28]: import nltk

In [29]: nltk.download('wordnet')
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
Out[29]: True

In [30]: from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

In [31]: lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()

In [32]: print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("caring"))
caring

In [33]: print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("forecasting"))
forecasting

In [34]: print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("running"))
running
```